# docking panel in xul

Tags: javascript, xul, docking

how can I make docking panel in xul. It should work like in firebug. I tried something like this:

```
myWindow = window.open("chrome://project/content/myWindow.xul", "someRandomName", "chrome");
```

and myWindow.xul is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utd-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<?xul-overlay href="chrome://project/content/myPanel.xul"?>

    <window id="dockedPanel" title="my super extension" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <hbox flex="1">
            <vbox id="myPanel"/>
        </hbox>
    </window>
```

myPanel.xul is my panel, and myPanel is id of vbox in myPanel.xul

When I open window like this, it looks quite like I wanted, but all buttons/other components don't work. For example if I have button in myPanel.xul:

```
<button id="myButton" label="button" onclick = "jsScriptFromOtherFile.someFunction()"/>
```

and if I click that button on myWindow, then someFunction isn't called. I don't know why, and how to make it working.

Comment: Can you post the full example that doesn't work. From your description it isn't clear what the problem is. For example, I assume you are including the script file in your XUL file, right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you expect all windows to share JavaScript code/state/scope, whatever you call it; 'jsScriptFromOtherFile' is not defined in any script loaded in 'myWindow.xul' or 'myPanel.xul', it's defined in the parent window that calls `window.open`.

Each 'window' (or tab, iframe, etc.) gets its own global object. To access variables from a different 'window' you first have to get a handle on that window. See [Working with windows in chrome code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code).